# Singular fibers of Kodaira dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I will be pleased if someone could give me some good reference to understand Singular fibers of Kodaira type. In fact I_6, I_3 and A_1. Thanks

Comment: There are many references. See e.g.
- Barth Peters Hulek Van de Ven Compact complex surfaces
- Silverman Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves (look foor Tate's algorithm)
- Tate, Algorithm for determining the type of a singular fiber in an elliptic pencil. In Modular functions of one variable, IV.
- Miranda, The basic theory of elliptic surfaces (This book is hard to find)

Note that an A_1 fiber is either a fiber of type II or of type I_1 in Kodaira's notation

Comment: Remke, your comment looks useful enough to be an answer.